# os x equivalent to ios's rootViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, rubymotion, macruby

What would be the OS X equivalent of ios' (Ruby style) :

```
@window.rootViewController = NSViewController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
```

There are two aspects :

- dealing with the absence of rootViewController in os x
- doing the equivalent of initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil), that fails on os x

I'm trying to build a window in code (without nib)... and follow along Pragmatic's Programmer Guide to RubyMotion (written for iOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of a "rootViewController" in OS X applications. This is because applications are made up of one or more windows and/or a menu bar, none of which is the "root".

You can, however, find the window controller starting from a view controller:

```
[[[self view] window] delegate];
```

If you are looking to call custom methods on the window controller, it is probably better to [create a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) so that assumptions about the controller don't get you into trouble.

The equivalent of `NSViewController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)` would be:

`[[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Method calls get nested in square brackets, methods with multiple parameters are simply `label1:parameter1 label2:parameter2...`

Usually, though, you would have a custom `NSViewController` subclass that you would instantiate instead.

Comment: thanks for rootViewController info. Do you know what the equivalent of   initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil) would be ?

Comment: Doh, I overlooked that part of the question, I have added the answer to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I had a single view controller owned by the window, so the following code worked for me:

```
let viewController = NSApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.contentViewController as! MyViewController
```

where `MyViewController` is my `NSViewController` subclass.

Comment: this worked for me despite having multiple viewControllers - I simply checked that the `contentViewController` was able to be downcast to the correct subclass before grabbing what I needed from it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset rootViewController like in iOS you can use this code:

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue:"Main"), bundle: Bundle.main)
let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "SIHome")) as! HomeViewController
NSApp.keyWindow?.contentViewController = homeViewController
```

- `NSApp` is a shortcut for `NSApplication.shared()`
- **rootViewController** is called **contentViewController** in OSX